# C# uno game ai select wild color by hand

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence

i was writing an uno AI but i faced a problem in wild card play..
i want the AI to select the best color to select in a wild card by his hand of cards but i couldn't get any idea doing it..

the card is a class which have Face string and Color enum

```
public class Card
    {
        public CardColor Color { get; set; }
        public string Face { get; set; }

        public Card(CardColor color, string face)
        {
            Color = color;
            Face = face;
        }
    }

    public enum CardColor
    {
        Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Wild 
    }
```

and each play has a list of cards

```
public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
```

now i need to select hand color to play the wild cards :/

Comment: Find out the colour with the highest frequency in `Cards`?

Comment: This becomes non-trivial quickly.  You have to define "best" color.  An "easy" AI might just pick the most popular color in its own hand.  A more advanced AI would probably keep track of what other players are playing to infer what they are doing.  If Blue is the most common card in your hand but the next player in line is down to 1 card and he has been favoring Blue, maybe that is no longer the best option?  After you define the logic you want to use in plain language, you can ask more focused questions about converting that into code.

Comment: i want it an simple and easy AI, but i couldn't get how to write the code which selects the color depends on its own hand..

Comment: @dazedandconfused - surely in the scenario you suggest the most common colour in `Cards` would be 'best' as this would mean the odds of the player with 1 card having that colour is reduced by the very virtue you hold more of them? However, I get you're point about defining 'best' :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment, if you want to determine the wild card colour by frequency of card colour in the list of cards you can do it like this:

```
var mostFrequentColor = Cards.GroupBy(c => c.Color)
                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                             .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Color)
```